# Fastlane Match environment variables are not picked up by build_app

Tags: ios, jenkins-pipeline, fastlane, fastlane-match

I started using fastLane and match for [codesigning](https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/) on jenkins. match is able to successfully create the certificates and provisioning profile. The `build_app` step however fails since the `pbxproj` file is setting the CODE_SIGN_STYLE to Automatic. I want to achieve the build without modifying the `pbxproj` file since the devs use automatic signing.

FastFile

```
        lane :upload_debug_test_flight do
          setup_jenkins
          match
          build_app(scheme: "MyWork Dev", clean: true, export_method: "app-store")
          upload_to_testflight(.....)
        end
```

Match file:

```
    git_url("git@github.mywork/cert_repo.git")
    storage_mode("git")
    type("appstore")
    api_key_path("./test.json")
    app_identifier(["com.mywork.mywork-test"])
    username("developer@mywork.com")
```

In our project.pbxproj we have

```
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = "Apple Development";
    CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Automatic;
    PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER= ''
```

Also tried the following, but still gym/build_app is not picking the match env variables:

```
            build_app(
                skip_profile_detection: true,
                export_method: "app-store",
                export_options:{
                    signingStyle: "manual",
                    provisioningProfiles:{
                        "com.mywork.mywork-test": "match AppStore com.mywork.mywork-test"
                    }
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 3):

Gym (`build_app`) uses the provisioning profile mapping defined by Match for archiving (`export_options`), but not for building the app (these are two different steps).

Thus, you need to either configure your Xcode project to use specific profiles, or update the `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER` value before calling `build_app`.

If developers only use the `Debug` configuration, you can specify different settings between `Debug` and `Release`. This way, you can keep the `Automatic` option for the `Debug` configuration and specify the code signing identity and profile manually for the `Release` configuration.

If you don't want to touch your Xcode project at all and define everything dynamically from fastlane, you can use the [update_code_signing_settings](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/update_code_signing_settings/#update_code_signing_settings) action to use the provisioning profile managed by Match:

```
match(...)
profile_mapping = Actions.lane_context[SharedValues::MATCH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MAPPING]
update_code_signing_settings(
    use_automatic_signing: false,
    path: "path/to/your/project.xcodeproj",
    profile_name: profile_mapping['app_identifier'] # app_identifier could be an environment variable: ENV['APP_ID']
)
build_app(...)
```

Another solution is to pass the `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER` variable to the `xcargs` option. Note that it will update the value in all your targets, so it may not work if you have an app extension with a different profile for example.

```
build_app(
    ...
    xcargs: "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER='profile_name'"
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped.

This is also discussed here:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20165

Comment: If my project has multiple bundle_ids, for example containing widget, do I iterate over the `bundle_id` and execute the `update_code_signing_settings` method with each `bundle_id`?

Comment: @Rakuyo I haven't tested it myself, but I would indeed execute the action for specific targets based on the Match mapping.